# Move a piece of string

Tags: javascript, string

So, I have this long application form that I made in contact form 7 plugin on WordPress.
The tags look like this:

```
[text text-758 "Building name"]
```

and I made a mistake: I forgot to add labels. It should look like this:

```
<label>Building name[text text-758]</label>
```

Now I have to make the changes in all the application.
My question ( I am a beginner in JavaScript): can I write a little script to do this for me?
I would rather learn to do it in plain JavaScript instead of Jquery.
Maybe regex would help? And insertBefore()?
I would like to do this in my console or say...codepen.
There are no id's or classes, just a big "string". 
I am stuck.

Comment: solve the initial problem before the page is get rendered. Text permutation with javascript throughout the page is not a good idea

Comment: I didn't yet publish the page. I just want to copy the whole thing and write a script that runs in the console or codepen, then just copy the result and only after publish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Roman in the comments, you should fix the source rather than applying a client-side patch.

That said, you can use Javascript locally to fix the source as well -- although Node.js might be a better option for this batch-kind of job.

*<sub>**Note:** `.insertBefore()` is a DOM manipulation method. Not a string manipulation method. That's why your question was ambiguous.</sub>*

```js
var str =
  'Hello World! [text text-758 "Building name"]' +
  'This is a test. [text text-123 "Foo"]';

str = str.replace(
  /\[([a-z]+ [a-z]+-\d+) "([^"]+)"\]/gi,
  "<label>$2[$1]</label>",
  str
);

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but that is one text field. What do I do about the others? There are 30 text fields similar to that one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should fix your tag building code anyway, but for now this thing can help:

```
var reg = /\[(.*)\s"(.*)"]/
  , test = '[text text-758 "Building name"]'

test.replace(reg, '<label>$2[$1]</label>') // should return what you need
```

Comment: make array of these and map them using provided regex to the form you need so you end up with array of correct label blocks

Comment: Oh man, trying to do that, but I have [] inside each string, sometimes twice...Do I have to escape them?